# Pulling specific word from dataframe string column and storing in new column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, split

I have a Python dataframe column `Name` who's elements always contain a first name, last name, and the word "over" or "under"

For example: `Name` = `[Michael Johnson Over, Michael Johnson Under, John Smith Over, John Smith Under]`

I'm trying to create a new column `Name2` that extracts either "Over" or "Under" from `Name`

So for the example above `Name2` = `[Over, Under, Over, Under]`

I've tried different variations of `.split` & `findall` but can't figure out how to get a new column that just has `Over` or `Under` in it, please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.str` is a property on `pd.Series` that exposes string-parsing functionality such as `.contains`. You can set a new column with boolean indexing where the condition is whether or not the row in `"Name"` contains the keywords `"Over"` or `"Under"`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Name": [
            "Michael Johnson Over",
            "Michael Johnson Under",
            "John Smith Over",
            "John Smith Under"
        ],
    }
)

df["Name2"] = None
df["Name2"][df["Name"].str.contains("Over")] = "Over"
df["Name2"][df["Name"].str.contains("Under")] = "Under"
print(df)
```

#### Output

```
    Name                    Name2
0   Michael Johnson Over    Over
1   Michael Johnson Under   Under
2   John Smith Over         Over
3   John Smith Under        Under
```

Comment: This works great! Thank you! Is there a way to extract the name before "Over" or "Under" into another new column?

Comment: Yes,

`df["Name3"] = None`  

`df["Name3"][over_mask] = df["Name"][over_mask].str.slice(0, -4)`  

`df["Name3"][under_mask] = df["Name"][under_mask].str.slice(0, -5)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas [`rsplit`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) to split the string from the end, and use `n` parameter to limit number of splits in output to one. You can also use the `expand=True` to split strings into separate columns.

```py
df[['First_Last','Name2']] = df['Name'].str.rsplit(' ', n=1, expand=True)
```

Output

```py
                    Name       First_Last  Name2
0   Michael Johnson Over  Michael Johnson   Over
1  Michael Johnson Under  Michael Johnson  Under
2        John Smith Over       John Smith   Over
3       John Smith Under       John Smith  Under
```